# Do I have to specify import when Python script is being run in Ipython?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, import, ipython

I am writing a script that I know I will run in Ipython.

I start Ipython as ipython --pylab.

This imports numpy, matplotlib, etc.

So do I have to specify these import statements again in my script?

I did not, and my script did not run.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the `%run -i` option.

Answer (score 1):

`--pylab` imports `numpy` both as `*` and `np`.  I always use `np.` to minimize confusion.

If I need `numpy` in my script, I include the usual `import numpy as np` line.  This lets me run the script from the shell.  I can also run it with `run ...` from within `IPython`.  I could also do an `import` in Ipython or some other script.

I've never tried omitting the `import numpy` line, and I don't see any need to start.  It doesn't save any time or space.  Make a habit of importing what you need, and don't assume the environment will do it for you.

Functions that you define and edit from with in IPython don't need their own import statements.

---

just tried this script:

```
def foo1(x):
   return np.sum(x)

def foo2(x):
   return x.sum()
```

Obviously I can load it with 'run'.  And `foo2(np.array([1,2,3]))` works because the array uses its own method.  But `foo1` produces a `NameError: global name 'np' is not defined`.